# How to improve the performance issue with Native plugins in Unity of android?

Tags: c#, android, performance, unity-game-engine, native

I write some math code of my game, I want to improve the performance, so I decide write it with the native C++ code, I using the NDK to build the .so file and put it in the plugins/Android, but I test it in the device(MI 6), I find that the performance is worse than the C# code(the same algorithm).
Test case: random calc 10000 times.
Is there anyone meet the issues before? and how can I improve the performance.

```
public static Pow(XFloat a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return 1;
    long res = XFloat.Factor;
    long basenum = a.n;

    bool positive = true;

    if (b < 0)
    {
        b = -b;
        positive = false;
    }

    while (b != 0)
    {
        if ((b & 1) == 1) res = (res * basenum) / XFloat.Factor;
        basenum = basenum * basenum / XFloat.Factor;
        b >>= 1;
    }

    if (res == 0)
        return 0;

    if (!positive)
        res = XFloat.Factor * XFloat.Factor / res;

    return res;
}

long long _DLLExport CPow(long long a, int b, long long f)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return 1;
    long long res = f;
    long long base = a;

    bool positive = true;

    if (b < 0)
    {
        b = -b;
        positive = false;
    }

    while (b != 0)
    {
        if ((b & 1) == 1) res = (res * base) / f;
        base = base * base / f;
        b >>= 1;
    }

    if (res == 0)
        return 0;

    if (!positive)
        res = f * f / res;

    return res;
}
```

Comment: There's always overhead when calling native code from managed code